# diagonalizability and row equivalency

Tags: linear-algebra

For each of the following four assertions, decide whether it is true or false.
If it is always true - prove it.
If it is false - give a numerical counter example that disproves the claim.

If A and B are row equivalent, then A is diagonalizable if and only if B is diagonalizable.

Comment: what do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: Could you give more context to your question? What are you struggling with?